# How do I export class functions, but not the entire class in a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, c++-cli

I have developed a Win32 DLL, providing the details below, and want to create a CLI/C++ wrapper for the functions Connnect and LogOut.

I know that entire classes and functions can be exported from a DLL.

```
class CClientLib
{
 public:
CClientLib (void);
// TODO: add your methods here.
__declspec(dllexport) bool Connect(char* strAccountUID,char* strAccountPWD);
__declspec(dllexport) void LogOut();

 private :

    Account::Ref UserAccount ;
void set_ActiveAccount(Account::Ref act)
{
   // Set the active account
}

Account::Ref get_ActiveAccount()
{
  return UserAccount;
    }

};
```

I want to have the class as the exported functions, Connect and LogOut, uses the function set / get.

Is it possible only to export the functions Connect and LogOut, and not the entire class.

Comment: hrm, I would guess if the methods are static, maybe, but not sure if this is possible with non-static methods

Comment: You could create a wrapper class and export that instead.

Comment: I know I am probably a year too late on this, but perhaps I will help some other readers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx - read especially part on selective import/export.

Comment: Since above link posted by @j_kubik seems to be dead now, and given the importance of this topic, here are the updated docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/using-dllimport-and-dllexport-in-cpp-classes?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend to declare an interface that will be exported and then implement it by your internal class.

```
class __declspec(dllexport) IClientLib {
 public:
    virtual bool Connect(char* strAccountUID,char* strAccountPWD) = 0;
    virtual void LogOut() = 0;
};

class CClientLib: public IClientLib {
...
};
```

Comment: If you were the shared library's user, how could you instantiate an object  of class `IClientLib`? The interface has not constructor, and the class that implements it is hidden (internal linakge)

Comment: @Dan You should provide a helper function i.e. `IClientLib *initializeClient()` or `const IClientLib *theClient();`. Have in mind that if you are going to allow users to `delete` IClientLib instances you should add a virtual destructor in IClientLib. `virtual ~IClientLib(){}`

Answer (score 0):

Consider what you are asking about... both `Connect` and `Logout` are non-static member functions, which means that you need to call them on an instance of the type: `intense.Connect()`. Now, if you do not export the class itself, you will not be able to create the `instance`, and whether `Connect` and `Logout` are exported or not makes no difference, they would be unusable.

An alternative would be not to export any of them, and provide exported free functions with the same functionality that apply to some instance of your class that is not *visible* outside of your DLL. Alternatively offer a third function that creates a *handle* into your library, where *handle* could be an opaque (`void*`) pointer to a dynamically allocated instance of your type, and then pass the *handle* as an extra argument to your free function versions of `Connect` and `Logout`. You will also need to add a fourth function to release that object.

Comment: And what if op doesn't allow dll users to create object at will but provides them with (possibly multiple) pointers that were created in dll by some other functions/classes? Then he might want to make invisible some inner-workings of his class and export only clean set of functions. This should be possible without creating an interface (unnecesary virtual calls) or C-like wrapper functions (call overhead, and generally wrong language ;) ). As long as not-exported methods are not virtual everything should work fine.

Comment: @j_kubik: Without an interface, what you are saying is that the type of the object inside the library and outside of it are different, right? That is a violation of the ODR in itself, so that is not a good solution. You can provide an interface type and extend it (and even do magic with casts and the order of definition to avoid having virtual functions (something similar to CRTP, without the T) and complicate your design potentially making it fragile... well, the alternative is a virtual interface, which is correct and safe. I would not call that *unnecessary*

Comment: It might not be a good solution, but it is definitely not uncommon solution;) I admit that additional overhead is usually not worth the trouble and your solution is conceptually better - but there are those who might feel different, so why should we forbid it to them? As long as they are aware of the risks, the tools are there to be used - no problem. And it is even mentioned in MSDN documentation, so it cannot be that obscure :P

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by simply creating two functions wich call the desired class methods end export them.
i.e.

```
CCLientLib g_clientLib;

__declspec(dllexport) void CClientLib_LogOut()
{
    g_clientLib.LogOut();
}
```

But I don't understand why you need this, since it's enough to mark the methods you don't want to be accessible with the "private" modifier (as done in your example).