# How to implement interface segregation when creating a Windows shared library in C++

Tags: c++, linker

I have a class implemented in `C++`. I want to create a shared library that exports that class, but only certain methods. For example, I want to apply internal linkage to all private members.

I have read the **problems** that `anoymous namespaces` can cause, so I have discarded that option. Instead, I want to try to use **interface segregation**, but **I don't know how to implement it in a shared library**. Let me explain:

Suppose you have the following code:

```
// MyLib.h
class MyLib {
public:
   int fun1() { return _i; }
   double fun2() { return _d; }
   bool fun3() { return _b; }

private:
   int _i;
   double _d;
   bool _b;
};
```

I would like to create a shared library that exports the symbol `MyLib` and only one of its methods, for example `fun1`.

I can't just mark MyLib as `dllexport`, since that will export all the class' symbols, including private members. So I want to create an interface with only one method and export it:

```
class __declspec(dllexport)  IMyLib {
   virtual int fun1() = 0;
};

class MyLib : public IMyLib {
   // Same as above...
};
```

This schema is explained in the following post: [How do I export class functions, but not the entire class in a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226580/how-do-i-export-class-functions-but-not-the-entire-class-in-a-dll)

**Now, my problem is that I don't understand, in the case of being using `MyLib.dll`, how could you instantiate an `IMyLib`** object, since the class that implements it is hidden (`internal linkage`), so you can't access it from a shared library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some broader scope you may take a look at the creational design patterns but the simplest method that could give you some idea is to add a factory method to your interface like:

```
class EXPORTED  IMyLib {
   virtual int fun1() = 0;
   static IMyLib* create();
};
```

and implement it in the DLL like:

```
IMyLib* IMyLib::create()
{
    return new MyLib;
}
```

You must also address the issue of deleting such an object. And this is one of the reasons you should not use the hardcoded directive `__declspec(dllexport)` Instead use a macro switching between `dllexport` and `dllimport`depending on the context. It will help with choosing the right `operator delete` defined in the DLL. Otherwise the Visual C++ compiler will use one from the client module which may not be compatible with the DLL. But it still may not be enough as the client module may be written even in a different language so to be safe add also `static void destroy(IMyLib*);` It will guarantee that the object is destroyed in the same DLL where it was created.

Comment: Yes,  using `__dllexport`directly was just for this example.